# Electron Configuration Logic

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, logic, chemistry

I am trying to create a method (in java) to figure out the Electron Configuration for an element.

Ex. 
He (2nd element: 2 electrons) Electron config: 1s<sup>2</sup>
    
O (8th element 8 electrons) Electron config: 1s<sup>2</sup> 2s<sup>2</sup> 2p<sup>4</sup>
    
Zr (40th element 40 electrons) Electron config: 1s<sup>2</sup> 2s<sup>2</sup> 2p<sup>6</sup> 3s<sup>2</sup> 3p<sup>6</sup> 4s<sup>2</sup> 3d<sup>10</sup> 4p<sup>6</sup> 5s<sup>2</sup> 4d<sup>2</sup>

How can I figure out the logic to calculate this? When to increment the s, p, d, and f shells, as well as figure out the superscript for each shell.

S max of 2 electrons (superscript max of 2)
P max of 6 electrons (superscript max of 6)
D max of 10 electrons (superscript max of 10)
F max of 14 electrons (superscript max of 14)

Recursion perhaps?

Comment: This should perhaps be on http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Shells -- perhaps ordered enums. Number of electrons, perhaps an enum map.

Comment: I'm sure you've tried something, right? Please share your latest unsuccessful attempt.

Comment: I've only tried on paper, but I still can't truly figure out how to do it in code.

Comment: I don't know how far along in chemistry you are, but I know that early chemistry classes like to teach filling electron orbitals according to the [Aufbau Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle). Keep in mind though, it's only a rule of thumb, and as the atomic number gets higher, there are more and more exceptions due to quantum mechanical and other effects.

Comment: I know of the Aufbau Principle, the Pauli exclusion Principle, and Hund's Rule. We learned them this week.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a class for represent the configuration with the following attributes:

```
private final boolean[] K = new boolean[ 2];
private final boolean[] L = new boolean[ 8];
private final boolean[] M = new boolean[18];
private final boolean[] N = new boolean[32];
private final boolean[] O = new boolean[32];
private final boolean[] P = new boolean[32];
```

`true` for an allocated place, false for a free place.

Example for potassium :

```
K[0] = true;
K[1] = true;
L[0] = true;
...
L[7] = true;
M[0] = true;
...
M[7] = true;
N[0] = true;
```